# Chrome Extension Rejected, Bad Manifest File. URLs in Permissions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this manifest file for a Chrome extension?

```
{
    "name": "Mobile Extension Name",
    "description": "Mobile Extennsion for Laptop/Desktop",
    "version": "2.941.7",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "omnibox": { "keyword" : "gomobile" },
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "local_path": "index.html"
        }
    },
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "permissions": [
        "https://mobile.prod-site.com/",
        "https://beta.prod-site.com/",
        "http://mobile.test-site.com/",
        "notifications",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "idle",
        "geolocation"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' chrome-extension://; object-src 'self' chrome-extension://; media-src 'self' chrome-extension://;", 
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon-16-beta.png",
        "128": "icons/icon-128-BETA.png"
    }
}
```

I have used this for a few years now without any incident, then about 1 month ago I attempted to upload a new Beta version of my extension and it is being rejected with the following error;

```
An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

The field permissions.http://mobile.prod-site.com/ is not allowed in manifest.
The field permissions.https://beta.prod-site.com/ is not allowed in manifest.
The field permissions.https://mobile.test-site.com/ is not allowed in manifest.
```

I have seen where some people recommend changing the URL in the permissions field to end in "*" or "/*".  No URL pattern is being accepted, even a wildcard URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update the extension because it is a [legacy packaged app](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps). The capabilities of legacy packaged apps was reduced in 2012, and announced at https://blog.chromium.org/2012/11/restricting-extension-apis-in-legacy.html:

> Beginning this week <sup>(November 2012)</sup>, you won’t be able to publish legacy packaged apps in the Chrome Web Store that request any of the following permissions:
>
> (a) any host permissions, including "`<all_urls>`"

I strongly recommend to [migrate from a legacy packaged app to an extension](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/migrating), because support for legacy packaged apps is going to be dropped, and they [will no longer be loaded in Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/migrate-your-legacy-packaged-apps-to.html) next year (June 2015).

Comment: Thanks Rob W.  Not the answer I wanted, but the answer I needed. I appreciate your input.